# How do I access Google Drive Revisions API using a service account?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

When I want to get file changes, I get the following error:

```
The user does not have sufficient permissions for file ***
```

My code:

```py
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'service.json', scopes=SCOPES)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
service.revisions().list(fileId=DOC_ID)
```

IAM:

[image]

P.S.: This file was created by me in docs.google.com.

Comment: Does the services account have permissions to access the file?

Comment: WOW! Thank you! It was so easy, but I didn't think of it. :D

Comment: I added the answer for visibility. If this answers your question please consider marking the question as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question, since it was added in the comment. The error message "The user does not have sufficient permissions for file ***" usually refers to a problem with the permissions in the file. To solved the issue you should share the file with the services account. This is base in the Google Documentation [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529)